# How to combine multiple WHERE condidtions in WITH and WHEREHAS in Laravel Eloquent query

Tags: laravel, eloquent-relationship, laravel-eloquent-resource

In below query the `awarded`, `banned`, `featured` and `published` parts are being ignored, why?

Query: Show me a list of all featured published books with an author that has been awarded and has not been banned.

```
$books = myBooks::with('authors')
            ->whereHas('authors', function ($query) {
                $query
                    ->where([
                        'awarded' => true,
                        'banned' => false
                    ]);
            })
            ->where([
                'featured' => true,
                'published' => true
            ])
            ->latest()
            ->get();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Create Multiple Where Clause Query Using Laravel Eloquent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325312/how-to-create-multiple-where-clause-query-using-laravel-eloquent)

Comment: [Laravel multiple WHERE clauses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43693136/laravel-multiple-where-clauses)

Comment: [Where Clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#where-clauses)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the syntax you are using documented anywhere. You can try doing:

```
$books = myBooks::with('authors')
            ->whereHas('authors', function ($query) {
                $query
                    ->where([
                        [ 'awarded', '=', true ],
                        [ 'banned',  '=', false ]
                    ]);
            })
            ->where([
                [ 'featured', '=', true ],
                [ 'published', '=', true ]
            ])
            ->latest()
            ->get();
```

Comment: you can also use the `withWhereHas()` instead of using the `with` and `whereHas` separately. which do the same. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads-with-relationship-existence

Answer (score 0):

Most likely some of these fields: `awarded`, `banned`, `featured` and `published` are present in both of your tables. For the query to work correctly in the conditions you need to specify the ownership of these fields

```
$books = Books::with('authors')
    ->whereHas('authors', function ($query) {
        $query
            ->where([
                'authors.awarded' => true,
                'authors.banned' => false,
            ]);
    })
    ->where([
        'books.featured' => true,
        'books.published' => true,
    ])
    ->latest()
    ->get();
```